# How to manipulate BufferedImage

Tags: java, image-processing, processing, bufferedimage

`Processing` has a class named `PImage` from which you can get an array of `int` that contains values for all pixels. Then, you manipulate this array and call `updatePixels()` and voila you have applied an effect to the image.

I was wondering if the same can be done in `BufferedImage` with some appropriate mechanism. I found that `BufferedImage` does indeed have a method to get pixels as `int[]`:

```
public int[] getRGB(int startX,
                    int startY,
                    int w,
                    int h,
                    int[] rgbArray,
                    int offset,
                    int scansize)
Returns an array of integer pixels in the default RGB color model (`TYPE_INT_ARGB`) and default sRGB color space, from a portion of the image data. 
Color conversion takes place if the default model does not match the image `ColorModel`. 
There are only 8-bits of precision for each color component in the returned data when using this method.
```

How do I modify these  pixels and show the appropriate changes in `BufferedImage` ?

I guess I will need to obtain a `WritableRaster` for the image and use

```
public void setPixels(int x,
                      int y,
                      int w,
                      int h,
                      int[] iArray)
```

but I am still unsure.

Comment: (tilts head)  How do you *want* to manipulate them?  For my tastes, I'd prefer to use a `BufferedImage`, get a `Graphics2D` and thereafter be able to change it by drawing things to it (lines, ellipses, text, images..) using affine transformations, clipping, strokes, gradients, rendering hints..  Call `repaint()` on the container and there it is onscreen.

Comment: @AndrewThompson How about making a colored image grayscale ? Applying some tinting filter ? Blurring it ? Sharpening it ?

Comment: OK you got me.  I tend to do much less of that area of image operations.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a `WritableRaster`, you have to choose a `ColorModel` first.
I think the RGB default should suit your needs.

```
ColorModel colorModel = ColorModel.getRGBdefault();
WritableRaster raster = colorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(width, height);
```

Then, you can fill it with your pixels and create a new `BufferedImage`.

```
raster.setPixels(0, 0, width, height, pixels);      
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, true, null);
```

And just as a reminder, here is a way to extract pixels from a `BufferedImage`:

```
Raster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
int[] pixels = raster.getPixels(0, 0, raster.getWidth(), raster.getHeight(), (int[]) null);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `PImage` class integrates a bit with the `BufferedImage` class:

```
//BufferedImage to PImage
PImage img = new PImage(yourBufferedImageInstance);

//PImage to BufferedImage
BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage)yourPImageInstance.getNative();
```